# Can I ignore org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionExceptions?

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My Apache Kafka producer (0.9.0.1) intermittently throws a

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException
```

My code that performs the Kafka send resembles this

```java
final Future<RecordMetadata> futureRecordMetadata = KAFKA_PRODUCER.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(kafkaTopic, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), jsonMessage));

try {
    futureRecordMetadata.get();
} catch (final InterruptedException interruptedException) {
    interruptedException.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException("sendKafkaMessage(): Failed due to InterruptedException(): " + sourceTableName + " " + interruptedException.getMessage());
} catch (final ExecutionException executionException) {
    executionException.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException("sendKafkaMessage(): Failed due to ExecutionException(): " + sourceTableName + " " + executionException.getMessage());
}
```

I catch `NotLeaderForPartitionException` within the `catch (final ExecutionException executionException) {}` block.

Is it OK to ignore this particular exception?

Has my Kafka message been sent successfully?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you receive `NotLeaderForPartitionException`, your data was **not** written successfully.

Each topic partition is stored by one or multiple Brokers (with one leader; the remaining brokers are called followers) depending on your replication factor. A producer needs to send new messages to the leader Broker (data replication to followers happens internally).

Your producer client does not connect to the correct Broker, ie, to a follower instead of the leader (or to a broker that is not even a follower any longer), and this broker rejects your send request. This can happen if the leader changed but the producer still has outdated cached metadata about which broker is the leader for a partition.

Comment: What is the solution for it?

Comment: @VinitGaikwad The producer will retry sending the data internally first (and will refresh it's metadata to learn about the new leader the data must be sent to) -- thus, the application get this exception only if all retries are exhausted. Hence, you might want to increase the `retries` config parameter for the producer. If you want to handle it at the application level (was seems to be the second best option compared to increasing producer retries), you would need to call `Producer.send()` to resend the data.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when attempting to use a Kafka cluster in Kubernetes. The Kubernetes cluster was hosted on a cloud instance. I attempted to run **Kafka producer** code from my **local machine**. During the first run, an `UnknownHostException` occurred. I resolved this by adding the Kafka Kubernetes service address to my `/etc/hosts` file.

Example:

```
10.160.160.60    kafka-controller-0.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-controller-1.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-controller-2.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

However, I then encountered a `NotLeaderOrFollowerException`. Despite trying multiple solutions, none seemed to work correctly. Restarting the local application would resolve the issue temporarily. However, the problem would reappear after subsequent restarts.

Ultimately, I moved my local application into the Kafka cluster, which **solved** the problem. The issue occurs because all Kafka broker addresses in my `/etc/hosts` file point to the same IP address. When the producer attempted to connect the Kafka topic leader, **Kubernetes Proxy** routed requests to random Kafka nodes, resulting in this issue.

I started working with single node Kafka on Docker locally. Avoid trying to connect to a Kafka cluster on a remote server. If necessary, you should open public access to **different IP:Port** combinations for each Kafka node and specify the list of all brokers in your local application configuration.